# Rails turbo stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

I am confused why i dont get 2 entries when i create a new quote with the following code.

My thought is that i would get an entry from the following:

1. the create method that returns the turbo_stream and renders the create.turbo_stream
2. the actionCable that im subscribed to.

if i remove the stream, i still get just 1 entry.
if i remove the append method in create.turbo_stream, i still get one entry ( from the cable)

WHY DONT I GET 2 with both enabled?

**controller:**
In create i have a response type of `format.turbo_stream.erb` along with the html response type.

**create.turbo_stream.erb:**

```
<%= turbo_stream.prepend "quotes", @quote %>
<%= turbo_stream.update Quote.new, "" %>
```

**View**

```
<%= turbo_stream_from( [current_company, "quotes"] ) %>
```

Quote model broadcast:

```
  broadcasts_to ->(quote) { [quote.company, "quotes"] }, inserts_by: :prepend
```

Comment: Can you also share the `broadcast_to` method defined in the `Quote` model?

Comment: @ThomasVanHolder , i just edited the question with that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've skipped the important part, the partial that you're rendering:

```html
# app/views/quotes/_quote.html.erb

<div id="<%= dom_id(quote) %>">
  <%= quote.content %>
</div>
```

Both of these:

```
turbo_stream.prepend "quotes", @quote
```

```
broadcasts_to ->(quote) { [quote.company, "quotes"] }, inserts_by: :prepend
```

eventually render a [turbo_stream_action_tag](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/v1.1.1/app/helpers/turbo/streams/action_helper.rb#L12) that uses the *_quote* partial as a template:

```
<turbo-stream action="prepend" target="quotes">
  <template>
    <div id="quote_1"> q1 </div>
  </template>
</turbo-stream>
```

On the front end, `turbo` processes that tag and prepends the template to the specified target `#quotes`:

```html
<div id="quotes">
  <div id="quote_1"> q1 </div>
</div>
```

Turbo `prepend` and `append` actions take the `id` of direct child nodes into account and replace them instead.

If you want to get duplicates, just wrap everything in a tag:

```html
# app/views/quotes/_quote.html.erb

<div>
  <div id="<%= dom_id(quote) %>">
    <%= quote.content %>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, doing that will mess up the `replace` action by forever nesting `div`.

---

> If the template’s first element has an id that is already used by a
> direct child inside the container targeted by dom_id, it is replaced
> instead of prepended.

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/streams#prepend*

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense now ! :) i actually wanted the current behaviour, i just could not understand why it was not double rendering! thanks alot!