# Turbo Stream returns correct html, but when mounted to the dom it's hidden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, hotwire-rails, turbo

I'm using rails 7 with tailwind

I have a form that I want users to be able to append select inputs to, so I've set up the form to use a turbo stream. It is almost working, but I'm seeing some odd, unexpected behavior.

When the turbo stream responds the network shows the correct html, but what's actually mounted to the dom includes

`type="hidden" and style="display: none;"` to the html.

The partial I *want* to render:

```
<select name="job[employee_ids]" id="job_employee_ids">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <% employees.each do |e| %>
    <option value="<%=e.id%>"><%= e.first_and_last_name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

but the html being mounted

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/append_employee" target="" style="display: none;"><input name="_method" value="get" type="hidden"><input name="authenticity_token" value="-R0L0z4JejbgHnvcQFtEmgvG4gSm29MOKuvko1YkkToXIIfEKAmMoN3Lb9Jykd_E4SaCIwq7Gu0TzAcyRf0-wA" type="hidden"><input type="submit"></form>
```

What's odd is the stream works properly, but only on the first request. Subsequent calls exhibit the hidden behavior, and the hidden elements are mounting to the dom outside of the target div.

Very confusing. Here's the behavior:

https://www.loom.com/share/9b890540bb8e416f931b31b1006a3b01

Comment: you can't really have multiple inputs with the same `name` attribute, the last one will override the previous inputs. also, when turbo appends a template it takes `id` into account and replaces element with the same id, so the first click is `append` and the second click is `replace` existing select `id="job_employee_ids"`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72751679/207090. no idea where the extra `form` tags come from (need more details, logs, controller, form etc).

Comment: Thanks @Alex I came to realize the replacement behavior when you have > 1 of the same ```name``` - I'll look at the post. For now I'm just using a multiple select dropdown